# Merb multidomain session cookie

Tags: ruby, merb

Is there a way to set session cookie work for all subdomains (e.g. *.domain.com) from Merb configuration file (config/init.rb)

Looking for something like

```
Merb::Config.use do |c|
  c[:session_cookie_domain] = '.domain.com'
end
```